# C++ display data based on selecting 2 inputs

Tags: c++

i have a problem where i want to display data if user sends 2 numbers.

Example :

```
1. book
2. car
3. ship
4. train
choose program [1/2/3/4] :
```

i have tried with `if(num_text == "1" && num_text == "2")` not working and `case 1 and 2` not working

```
if(num_text == "1" && num_text == "2") {
 // display data 1. book and 2. car if inputs 1,2 or 1/2 or 1 2
} else {
 
}
```

so later if the user chooses 2 then what appears is the number according to the choice.

```
Example inputs : 1,2 or 1/2 or 1 and 2
Output : data 1 and 2 display
```

i just need what if the user selects 2 numbers, and display the selected data

I'm a beginner using C++, I hope you help my problem.

Comment: Please post a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can try your code. Also, "not working" is a very vague description and does not help others understand your problem.

Comment: *"i have tried with `if(num_text == "1" && num_text == "2")`"* -- tried what with this? What did you expect would happen, what actually happened, and are you expecting `num_text` to simultaneously be both `"1"` and `"2"`?

Comment: num_text is the input data (select program) which I call to get verification if the data is the same. by using if statement

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why your condition `if(num_text == "1" && num_text == "2")` doesn't work is fact that you compare one variable with two different values. And because one string variable cannot hold two or more string values, this statement is always false. In order to make this program work correctly, you have to split input into numbers and then compare each of them.

Comment: how to get 2 variables with if statement? or use a switch case break?. i have a problem if the user selects 2 numbers.

Comment: You can't. However you could compare single characters of the string, but it's very inefficient. For me, you should split your input string into words (tokens) using `std::strtok()` function and then convert these words into numbers, with `std::atol()` function.

Comment: here I do not destroy but I want if the user enters a number and selects 2 numbers, it will display the selected data.

Comment: Only two numbers? Not more? Then You can use `std::sscanf()` function to extract data from string. But if you want to let user enter unknown number of values, you have to use `std::strtok()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string program[4] = { "book", "car", "ship", "train" };

void options(string str)
{
    if (str == "1") {
        std::cout << "You chose the option: " + program[0] + "\n";
    }
    else if (str == "2") {
        std::cout << "You chose the option: " + program[1] + "\n";
    }
    else if (str == "3") {
        std::cout << "You chose the option: " + program[2] + "\n";
    }
    else if (str == "4") {
        std::cout << "You chose the option: " + program[3] + "\n";
    }
}

void split_c(string str)
{
    string w = "";
    for (auto x : str)
    {
        if (x == ',')
        {
            w = "";
        }
        else {
            w = w + x;
        }
        options(w);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string optionStr("Choose an option number: [1] [2] [3] [4]:\n");
    cout << optionStr;
    string option;
    getline(cin, option);
    split_c(option);
}
```

**Example Input A:** 2,4

**Output:**

[image]

**Example Input B:** 4,1,3,2

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your task I would say to do this:
Suppose you want to do something when the user inserts two numbers "x", "y", you have different options, the first is to use if/else construct
So, print the message to get the inputs x, y prompted by user, and then
If(x=="value you chose" & & y=="second value you chose)
{statement}
Else
{Statement}
.
The second way is to use switch construct, that I suggest you see, it can be very useful
Tell me if there is something I did not answer.

Comment: thanks for understanding, but i have done that and get no data if user select 2 data.

Comment: There must be something that you have not done correctly, please attach your code, so I can verify where is the mistake

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).